# Sorting animated GIFs in SVG without stopping the animation using D3/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, d3.js, animated-gif

My D3-based visualization produces an HTML5 SVG element with animated GIFs in it. For simplicity, take this example:

```
<svg>
  <image href="animated.gif"></image>
<svg>
```

Upon mouseover, I'd like to highlight the image by putting a circle behind with a fading gradient for a glow effect. As SVG renders elements on top of each other, the output must look like this:

```
<svg>
  <circle class="gloweffect"></circle>
  <image href="animated.gif"></image>
<svg>
```

After two wasted days, I gave up trying to insert the circle element at the correct position immediately with D3's insert. It just didn't work, esp. since the visualization contains lots of other stuff and the insert position is hard to express.

So instead, I use D3's append to add the circle at the end. Then I call a sorter which removes all elements from the SVG, sorts them, and re-appends them in the correct order:

```
<svg>
  <image href="animated.gif"></image>
  <circle class="gloweffect"></circle>
<svg>

--> remove everything

<svg>
<svg>

--> sort and reinsert

<svg>
  <circle class="gloweffect"></circle>
  <image href="animated.gif"></image>
<svg>
```

And here comes the challenge: This works fine in all browsers, except ... wait for it ... IE9. (Okay, lame wait.)

As soon as the image element is removed, IE9 stops the GIF animation and does not restart or continue it upon reinsertion. The image simply gets stuck at the first frame and stays that way.

So my question: Is there a way to make IE9 continue the animation after reinsertion? I found plenty of old threads regarding regular img elements, esp. suggesting to reset the picture in a delayed thread, but none of them seems to work for the image element in SVG.

--Florian

Comment: By ' I call a sorter' do you mean use `.sort()` with a custom function or have you implemented something else? Might be helpful if you provide some code relating how you are doing things. jsfiddle?

Comment: Why is it so hard to find the proper insert position? Removing/inserting elements will force relayout/repaints and that can be expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inserting and removing elements (which is expensive and error prone) just make them invisible, you could do something such as...

```
<svg>
  <g class="glow">
    <circle class="gloweffect"></circle>
    <image href="animated.gif"></image>
  </g>
<svg>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
g.glow .gloweffect {
  opacity: 0;
}

g.glow:hover .gloweffect {
  opacity: 1;
}
```